# border not working correctly on links html

Tags: html, css, border

So I'm learning to make websites in html and  css. recently i encountered the error which didn't happened to me before: 
  then i adding border to link in css, i cant get bottom and top borders to appear (that's a huge issue because i want to use border-bottom)

```
a.navi:link{color: black;}
a.navi:hover{color: black;
border-bottom: 5px solid #0ecf5b;}
#navigation li{
display: inline-block;
font-family: Courier New;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 32px;
padding: 5px 25px;
background: #ffffff;
/*border-bottom: 5px solid #0ecf5b;*/
}
```

however if I'm adding border-bottom: to navigation li{} im getting this border

 (#navigation li{} is list items surrounded by

```
<a href="..." class="navi">
```

tags)

 
Html code:

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <a href="Index.html" class="navi"><li>Home</li></a>
        <a href="web.html" class="navi"><li>Some-Stuff</li></a>
        <a href="logo.html" class="navi"><li>About</li></a>
        <a href="game.html" class="navi"><li>Contacts</li></a>
        <a href="about.html" class="navi"><li>Others</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `<a>` tags inside your `<li>` tags.
For example:

```
<li><a href="Index.html" class="navi">Home</a></li>
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kb3su8og/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want your links underlined, which would be better if you created a div underneath the link and the colored that appropriately, but to do borders try something like this for your html:

```
<nav id="navigation">
<ul class="navi">
    <a href="Index.html" class="home"><li>Home</li></a>
    <a href="web.html" class="someStuff"><li>Some-Stuff</li></a>
    <a href="logo.html" class="about"><li>About</li></a>
    <a href="game.html" class="contacts"><li>Contacts</li></a>
    <a href="about.html" class="others"><li>Others</li></a>
</ul>
```

and have your css reflect the changes with:

```
navi > a:hover {
border-bottom //that stuff
```

What that does is when a link is hovered over it does whatever you want. I am away from my computer so I can not test the code but I think this will work if not there are tons of youtube tutorials on this exact matter. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `<a>` tag inside `<li>` tag, it should be

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="navi">Stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
ul{list-style:none;}
a{display:block;text-decoration:none;}
li{display:inline-block;}
li:hover > a{color: black;border-bottom: 5px solid #0ecf5b;}
#navigation a{
font-family: Courier New;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 32px;
padding: 5px 25px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
   <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="navi">Stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navi">Stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navi">Stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the more standard way to do what you want would be to put your `a` tags inside your `li`'s, and use styles to make sure they fill the whole space, such as `display: block`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
}

li a.navi {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

li a.navi:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="navi">One link</a></li>
  <li><a class="navi">Second link</a></li>
</ul>
```

This may not be the style you are going for, I'm just guessing based on the snippet you provided.